# android.view.InflateException - Error inflating class android.widget.EditText

Tags: android, exception

Hello I'm trying to show a custom AlertDialog on the screen.
I'm inflating an layout into the dialog, this layout includes Two TextViews, one RatingBar and one EditText.

When I try to popup the dialog I'm getting this exception :

> E/AndroidRuntime(12989):
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error
>   inflating class android.widget.EditText

**Important point is this error occurs on Android 2.3.x Devices, It works great on Android 4.x**

dialog_comment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/DialogCommentRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:stepSize="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/DialogCommentRatingBar"
        android:text="Yorumunuz"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DialogCommentComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="?android:attr/editTextBackground"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Oyunuz"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CommentDialog.java

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_comment, null);

        final RatingBar rating=(RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.DialogCommentRatingBar);
        final EditText comment=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.DialogCommentComment);      

        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setView(view);

        builder.setTitle("Enter Your Comment!");
        return builder.create();

    }
```

How do I show AlertDialog

```
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        CommentDialog commentDialog = new CommentDialog();
        commentDialog.show(fm, "fragment_comment_dialog");
```

Comment: Try this: LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); Maybe it helps. Actually try to debug. I think you give null view.

Comment: @fobus try removing the background attribute from the EditText and see if it makes any difference

Comment: remove this line 
        android:background="?android:attr/editTextBackground" from EditText & update this line   final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_comment, null,false);

Comment: Yes removing background attribute fixed my problem.

Comment: did u solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

with

```
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted my EditView (Plain Text text field), dropped another one into content_....xml and did not change any styling this time.  Everything ran correctly with the default styling on the EditView.